# Any chess engine that can start from the middle of a game

Tags: engines, stockfish, uci

(i) Is there any Chess engine that can accept a partial game? E.g. `1. d4 d5 1. c4 Nf6 etc.` and then start either as White or Black. I want to analyze some of my moves and want to use the Chess engine to understand what a computer would do?

(ii) I can do coding in Python. I haven't used PyChess before. I noticed that PyChess supports multiple Chess engines. Can I use/modify PyChess to accept partial games, i.e. I was wondering if there any functions / modules in PyChess that can help me with creating a function / module which I can use to analyze moves after a partial game? I have no need for GUI per se, a simple output, showing what the computer is likely to do, is what I am interested in?

p.s. I am a total newbie to UCI interface (nothing new about Wiki) as well as newbie on how engines like Stockfish work and newbie to PyChess as well.

Comment: UCI allows you to create any FEN position.

Comment: The protocol also allows you to specify d4, d5, c4 move sequence. Please take a look at the UCI specification.